# ck progress seems struck ,table canno't merge and connected ,then a lot of close_wait

Tags: clickhouse

I have a cluster consited of one distribute node and 2 shards 4 replicas.
I insert batch data into one os the replicas which is not leader at a speed about 80~130 million rows/second。abount 15 minutes later,the produce data progress can't insert data successfully,the error log shows too many parts because this replica doesn't merge data.At the same time ,this shard's leader replica merge data successfully.This replica'progress is alive but it seems struck. And the clickhouse_client can't login in and the distribute query to the replica will be timeout and this replica has too many close_wait connections.

It's hard to reproduce.I only meet several times in the past half year.You can test to insert into one of the replica at a very high speed.
ClickHouse server version that i use is 20.1.6.30.

These are the screenshots i capture then.

1.[the picture shows the too many parts error](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20318636/83368560-d6867700-a3eb-11ea-89dd-c5cf6472d7ae.png)

2.[this picture shows the connections status](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20318636/83369105-c079b600-a3ed-11ea-969d-73740796b14d.png)

The next day i met this problem again,the below log shows that the inserts and merges all don't work now!

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1 Jun 2 14:12 format_version.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79020_79020_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79021_79021_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79022_79022_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79023_79023_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79024_79024_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79025_79025_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79026_79026_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79027_79027_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79028_79028_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_insert_441968_79029_79029_0
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441966_0_2412_4
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:10 tmp_merge_441966_13807_14060_3
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:10 tmp_merge_441966_8504_8764_3
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441967_33439_33544_3
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441967_33714_33764_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_100_125_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_126_150_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_1729_1753_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_1805_1829_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_181_205_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_1830_1854_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_206_230_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4039_4063_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4069_4094_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4441_4464_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4465_4489_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4566_4590_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_4591_4615_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_531_555_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_556_580_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_6854_6878_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_6924_6947_2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7083_7091_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7092_7098_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7099_7108_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7132_7141_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7151_7159_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7170_7177_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7178_7184_1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 2 16:13 tmp_merge_441968_7185_7191_1
```

Comment: you need to monitor errors at ZK servers

also check for errors system.merges and system.replication_queue

Comment: Thank you,today,i'll test it as you say.

Comment: BTW,when in this situation,clickhouse-client can't login in.It shows the error:Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection reset by peer, while reading from socket (ip:9000).Ine the data directory,there only is one temp fetch and one temp_merge:
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun  4 10:03 tmp_fetch_442005_439_558_3
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun  4 10:03 tmp_merge_442002_1974_1978_1

Comment: need to see CH server logs

Comment: Today,i found that in the /proc/ckpid/fd,there ara so many socket created but not use.

Comment: lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 994 -> socket:[80756151]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 995 -> socket:[80756154]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 996 -> socket:[80747433]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 997 -> socket:[80747434]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 998 -> socket:[80747435]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  6 10:01 999 -> socket:[80747436]
[root@bd-server-8 ~]# ll /proc/73589/fd/|wc -l
4270
It seems a bug of CH.